# Plotting a "sequence logo" using ggplot2?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

Is it (reasonably) possible to plot a [sequence logo plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_logo) using ggplot2?

There is a package to do it which is based on "grid" called "[seqLogo](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.3/bioc/html/seqLogo.html)", but I was wondering if there could be a ggplot2 version of it.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I think this is an abomination of a plot, and hope there isn't a way in ggplot2 to do it!

Comment: Brandon, yes.  Hadley:  :D  , so what should I go with? mosaic?

Comment: it would seem that it would be pretty easy to generate a less ugly plot that represented the same information by simply stacking bar plots. You might have to work a little harder to get the annotation on the x axis right.

Comment: Tal, could you provide some sample data? You could probably just do this with geom_text()

Comment: These sequence plots are a very common method to represent sequence motifs in biology.  I understand that stacked bars could be reasonable for DNA, which only has a 4 letter alphabet, however, for an amino acid sequence the alphabet has 22 letters.

Comment: @Tal Galili not sure if you have done this but you might want to ask this question over at http://biostar.stackexchange.com/, because it is focused solely on bioinformatics related questions.

Comment: I recently wrote an R wrapper for the common web logo python software. You can find it [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWebLogo/index.html) (binaries will be up soon):

Comment: I think this is an important, commonly used type of plot in bioinformatics, and so I hope there is a way in ggplot2 to do it!

Comment: There is now https://github.com/omarwagih/ggseqlogo

Comment: @by0 please write your comment as a full answer so I could mark it. This is the package I was hoping for when originally writing my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[ggseqlogo](https://github.com/omarwagih/ggseqlogo)** should be what you're looking for. I hope this can relieve some of the frustrations I’m sure many of you have when it comes to plotting sequence logos in R

Comment: Hi Omar, Can ggseqlogo works on data frame? I have the amino acids and their counts and percentage and I'd like to plot them.

Answer (score 12):

I'm submitting a `ggplot2` attempt that is somewhat similar to the Leipzig/Berry solution above.  This format is a *little bit* closer to the standard logogram.

But my solution, and I think any `ggplot2` solution, ***still falls short because `ggplot2` does not offer control over the aspect ratio of plotting symbols***.  This is the core capability that (I think) is required for generating sequence logos and that is missing from `ggplot2`.

Also note: I used the data from [Jeremy Leipzig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445075/2451238), but I did not do any corrections for small sample sizes or for %GC values different than 50%.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

 freqs<-matrix(data=c(0.25,0.65,0.87,0.92,0.16,0.16,0.04,0.98,0.98,1.00,0.02,0.10,0.10,0.80,0.98,0.91,0.07,0.07,0.11,0.05,0.04,0.00,0.26,0.17,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.00,0.29,0.17,0.01,0.03,0.00,0.00,0.32,0.32,0.53,0.26,0.07,0.02,0.53,0.18,0.96,0.01,0.00,0.00,0.65,0.01,0.89,0.17,0.01,0.09,0.59,0.12,0.11,0.04,0.02,0.06,0.05,0.49,0.00,0.00,0.02,0.00,0.04,0.72,0.00,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.02,0.49),byrow=TRUE,nrow=4,dimnames=list(c('A','C','G','T')))

freqdf <- as.data.frame(t(freqs))

freqdf$pos = as.numeric(as.character(rownames(freqdf)))

freqdf$height <- apply(freqdf[,c('A', 'C','G','T')], MARGIN=1,
                       FUN=function(x){2-sum(log(x^x,base=2))})

logodf <- data.frame(A=freqdf$A*freqdf$height, C=freqdf$C*freqdf$height,
                     G=freqdf$G*freqdf$height, T=freqdf$T*freqdf$height, 
                     pos=freqdf$pos)

lmf <- melt(logodf, id.var='pos')

quartz(height=3, width=8)

ggplot(data=lmf, aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(pos)), y=value))  +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=variable,order=value), position='stack', 
        stat='identity', alpha=0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=variable, size=value, order=value, vjust=value),
        position='stack') +
    theme_bw()

quartz.save('StackOverflow_5438474.png', type='png')
```

That produces this graph:

[image: Not bad, but not quite a sequence logo plot]

Answer (score 10):

I have implemented an alternative designed by Charles Berry, which addresses some of the weaknesses of seqLogos discussed ad nauseam in the comment section below. It uses ggplot2:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("leipzig/berrylogo")
library("berrylogo")
freqs<-matrix(data=c(0.25,0.65,0.87,0.92,0.16,0.16,0.04,0.98,0.98,1.00,0.02,0.10,0.10,0.80,0.98,0.91,0.07,0.07,0.11,0.05,0.04,0.00,0.26,0.17,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.00,0.29,0.17,0.01,0.03,0.00,0.00,0.32,0.32,0.53,0.26,0.07,0.02,0.53,0.18,0.96,0.01,0.00,0.00,0.65,0.01,0.89,0.17,0.01,0.09,0.59,0.12,0.11,0.04,0.02,0.06,0.05,0.49,0.00,0.00,0.02,0.00,0.04,0.72,0.00,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.02,0.49),byrow=TRUE,nrow=4,dimnames=list(c('A','C','G','T')))
p<-berrylogo(freqs,gc_content=.41)
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Does it generalize naturally to amino acid sequences?  Can you get the x-axis annotation (consensus or most probable sequence -- I don't know what the capital letters in the example above signify), possibly by adding a mini-plot with a fixed y value?

Comment: above 0 is "more favored than background"

I will work on the consensus issue along with ambig nt's. AA's will take some time.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the 'problems' you mention and how your suggest to solve them? I find it less easy to get the main information since ~80% of the plot shows no/redundant data, but maybe that's just because I am not used to the representation. Besides, I do not see how your link is supposed to help since the linked website doesn't contain that info either. So far I see an advert for your package (which might be great), a link to a link to a publication of yours and a plot that is not explained other than being 'better' than what the OP asked for without any code how to get it.

Comment: Very well. seqLogos suffer from the winner-take-all stacking problem, where if one residue is only slightly more favored than another, it gets top billing. The -3 position of the OP's logo is a case in point - A is in first, G is in second position but essentially it is a dead heat.  Secondly, a nucleotide is highly disfavored it simply disappears from a seqLogo, when the repulsion for that residue might be the most interesting story biologically. Finally, I think seqLogos look like total ass. That is subjective but it played no small role in my motivation to develop the berryLogo package.

Comment: How does your plot improve that? still A would be above G. And that it's close you can tell by the size in th OP's example plot. I agree that the 'consensus' sequence is problematic in this case, so let's say I don't put it. Also, I still do not see a reason to go from a (to mind mind) well interpretable unit like 'bits' to 'log rel. freq.'. Also, I think a good SE answer should contain code how to obtain your result (compare [by0](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1312519/by0)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23215998/2451238).

Comment: a berryLogo does not hide highly disfavored nucleotides - it features them. And if two nucleotides are very close in frequency then they will be overlapping not placed on a podium. Honestly I doubt most biologists understand enough information theory to know what "bits" mean but at least with a berryLogo you can tell which nucleotides happen more often than not. I'll post the code. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Thx for updating with code. You have a point regarding disvavored nucleotides. I would still prefer using bits + I doubt that somebody understanding log rel. freqs. would fail comprehending basic information theory. ;) +1 for a nice alternative & good discussion. :)

Comment: Also note that `install_github("leipzig/berrylogo")` may be preferred over `install_github("berrylogo","leipzig")` (`Warning message: Username parameter is deprecated.`)

Comment: just to follow up on this thread, LOGOs that use negative values for disfavored nucleotides are now the predominant type found in journal articles

Answer (score 4):

No direct way to do so in ggplot2, as far as I'm concerned.

However, check out RWebLogo. It's an R wrapper I have written for the WebLogo python library. You can download it from [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWebLogo/index.html) and it's hosted on [github](https://github.com/omarwagih/RWebLogo)

Simple example:

```
# Load package
library('RWebLogo')

# Sample alignment
aln <- c('CCAACCCAA', 'CCAACCCTA', 'AAAGCCTGA', 'TGAACCGGA')
# Plot logo to file
weblogo(seqs=aln, file.out='logo.pdf')

# Plot logo to R graphics device (uses generated jpeg logo and raster package)
weblogo(seqs=aln, plot=TRUE, open=FALSE, format='jpeg', resolution=600)
```

For more options see `?weblogo` or `?plotlogo`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative option. [motiflogo](https://github.com/zhilongjia/motiflogo) is a new representation of motif (sequence) logo implemented by ggplot2. Two aspects could be considered.

1. As a canonical motif logo representation
2. As a SNP-specific motif logo representation

[image: a canonical motif logo representation]
[image: a SNP-specific motif logo representation]

Comment: The "sequence logo" portion does not seem to relate to what looks like the "consensus sequence" along the x-axis. Can you explain briefly how the x-axis labels on positions 6 and 8 relate to the high-entropy bases shown along the y-scale?

Comment: @AlexReynolds The letters at x-axis are SNP and letters shown in the figure are motif in Figure 2. Of course, the SNP and the motif are highly matched, though not perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [`gglogo`](https://github.com/heike/gglogo) package (also on CRAN, yet another amazing ggplot2 extension by Heike Hofmann).

This package that produces plots like these:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gglogo)
ggplot(data = ggfortify(sequences, "peptide")) +      
  geom_logo(aes(x=position, y=bits, group=element, 
     label=element, fill=interaction(Polarity, Water)),
     alpha = 0.6)  +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

The example is from https://github.com/heike/gglogo/blob/master/visual_test/logos.R and there's a manuscript on the package here: https://github.com/heike/logopaper/blob/master/logos.Rmd