# How do I plot a stacked barplot of letters with non-standard height-to-width ratio?

Tags: r

I am interested in representing some data in a plot as letters.

Image a stacked barplot, but instead of the individual bars, I want to use A-Z letters.

text() allows me to insert text, but not to specify an exact height and width stretching the letter.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think a visual example (think, drawing it on a napkin and snapping a cell-phone picture) would be helpful for people trying to answer your question.

Comment: you can fill a range with letters, like `text(x, y1:y2, "A")`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen : I am basically looking to recreate something along the lines of this [link](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v6/n4/fig_tab/nmeth.f.247_F3.html)

Comment: There's some discussion of sequence logos [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438474/plotting-a-sequence-logo-using-ggplot2).

Comment: I think I've seen things like this over at http://www.biostars.org before.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen : Thanks for the edit! I really want to make my own version - I just need help to figure out how to plot the scalable letters.

Comment: I don't have much experience with this, but think that given the domain, you may find more help at biostars.